# What is the star icon in notification bar on Lollipop?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notification-icons

Does anyone know what this icon means? The device is running Android 5.0 Lollipop.

[image]

Comment: From the placement on the notification bar, it is a system icon. Most systems are customized, so it will be necessary to know the device type and the Android OS on it, before knowing for certain what system component this could be reporting on. Please edit the question with these details.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This means that you only have priority notifications enabled. Pressing a volume button will allow you to select different notifications which show/make a sound.

There is a choice between no notifications, all notifications, and priority notifications, which can be changed by pressing a volume button. Going into Settings/Sound & notification allows you to set which notifications have priority, such as only showing SMS and missed calls.

More help can be found here: https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6111294

Answer (score 0):

In Samsung Galaxy S4, it is called "Interruptions" under "Sound and notifications" menu.